# How to determine if need to git_commit_create() after the merge()?

Tags: merge, pull, libgit2

When I use libgit2 to update data, pull seem to create unnecessary short-term branches and merges which are a headache to resolve. and each merge produced a new oid, so there should be a function to determine if a merge commit is needed before the merge commit. wondering if it is a good practice, then what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to analyze whether a merge is needed between two branches, or if instead it is fast-forwardable, use the [`git_merge_analysis`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/f55accce05c3eff9a3ef09a06e80c09135328790/examples/merge.c#L333) function:

```
git_merge_analysis_t analysis;
git_merge_preference_t preference;
int error = git_merge_analysis(&analysis, &preference, repo, merge_heads, merge_head_len);

if (analysis == GIT_MERGE_ANALYSIS_FASTFORWARD) {
    /* You can simply do a fast-forward */
} else {
    /* You need to do a true merge */
}
```

You may wish to examine the `preference` to know whether the user has asked to never fast-forward.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely@Edward Thomson

Comment: How to get
"merge_heads" parameters.

Comment: It's the things that you want to merge.  If you want to merge branch `foo` into branch `master`, then get the annotated_commit that `foo` points to and the annotated_commit that `master` points to.  `merge_heads` is an array containing those two commits.

Comment: OK,Thank you once again.